# Spring Integration http-inbound-gateway / RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I am new to Spring Integration. I am trying to build a simple application using http-inbound-gateway. 
Below is the Runtime exception i am getting.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping$1 does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract path()[Ljava/lang/String; of interface org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:305) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForEndpoint(IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:160) ~[spring-integration-http-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.detectHandlerMethods(IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:98) ~[spring-integration-http-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:249) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:208) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:196) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:164) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.onApplicationEvent(IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:177) ~[spring-integration-http-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.onApplicationEvent(IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:71) ~[spring-integration-http-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at com.cerner.api.MedicationManagementApplication.main(MedicationManagementApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
```

Below is the code files.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:integration.xml")
public class MedicationManagementApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MedicationManagementApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

POJO

```
@Entity
public class Medicine {

@Id
private String medId;

private String medName;
private String expDate;

public Medicine(String medId, String medName, String expDate) {
    this.medId = medId;
    this.medName = medName;
    this.expDate = expDate;
}
public Medicine() {

}
public String getMedId() {
    return medId;
}
public void setMedId(String medId) {
    this.medId = medId;
}
public String getMedName() {
    return medName;
}
public void setMedName(String medName) {
    this.medName = medName;
}
public String getExpDate() {
    return expDate;
}
public void setExpDate(String expDate) {
    this.expDate = expDate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Medicine [medId=" + medId + ", medName=" + medName + ", 
expDate=" + expDate + "]";
}

}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class MedicineService {

@Autowired
private MediceneRepository medicineRepo;

private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

public List<Medicine> getAllMedicines() {
    System.out.println("== Service called==");
    List<Medicine> medicine = new ArrayList<Medicine>();
    medicineRepo.findAll().forEach(medicine::add);
    log.info("Returning from service with medicine data");
    return medicine;
}
```

}

Service Activator

```
@Component("medicineServiceActivator")
public class MedicineServiceActivator {

private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

@Autowired
private MedicineService medicineService;

public Message<?> get(Message<?> msg) {
    log.info("GET method");
    System.out.println("===== get method called ====");
    List<Medicine> medLst = medicineService.getAllMedicines();
    return 
MessageBuilder.withPayload(medLst).copyHeadersIfAbsent(msg.getHeaders())
            .setHeader("http_statusCode", HttpStatus.OK).build();
}
```

}

Repository

```
public interface MediceneRepository extends CrudRepository<Medicine, String> 
{

}
```

Please help me , I am trying to get the solution why the exception is coming but not able to figure out.
Thanks In advance.

Integration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration- 
http-4.1.xsd">
<int:channel id="responseChannel" />
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel" reply- 
channel="responseChannel" supported-methods="GET" path="/getAllMedicines">
<int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" 
produces="application/json" /></int-http:inbound-gateway>
<int:service-activator ref="medicineServiceActivator" method="get" input- 
channel="requestChannel" output-channel="responseChannel" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Perhaps some mismatched jars (spring-integration-http Vs. spring-web), Show your Pom. Also `spring-integration-4.1.xsd` is very, very old.

Comment: Thanks Gary.  I have solved the problem. It was due to the jar only. There was a version mismatch in name space and Pom Dependency of Spring Integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the version mismatch of Spring Integration in POM.xml and the namespace links